# How to echo character from character code in shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell

How can we convert the character code to character in bash?

I am using MAC and using shell script.

I have a variable in script eg:

```
$name="Cat \&amp; Rat"
```

Now I want to echo this string as

```
Cat & Rat
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It's a plain string, why do you have an escaping backslash?

Comment: Also `$name=` is an invalid assignment; you should use `name=` without a dollar sign in shell script.

Comment: Sounds like you want to decode HTML or XML character entity references, correct? Which entities need to be recognized? As @Jean asked: why there is a `\ ` before `&`? Please clarify by editing your question.

Answer (score 2):

`perl`, which comes preinstalled on OSX, allows you to decode HTML and XML entities robustly:

```
perl -MHTML::Entities -C -pe 'decode_entities $_' <<<"Cat \&amp; Rat. 3&gt;2. 6&apos;"
# -> Cat \& Rat. 3>2. 6'
```

This recognizes the [252 HTML 4 entities plus `&apos;`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML), which includes all 5 predefined XML entities, and, in a UTF-8-based locale (as is the case on OSX), treats both input and output as UTF-8.

The `\` before the `&` is, however, retained.
If all your `&` instances are really `\`-escaped and you want to remove the backslash, simply use Bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to strip the `\` instances before passing the string to `perl`:

```
name="Cat \&amp; Rat"
perl -MHTML::Entities -C -pe 'decode_entities $_' <<<"${name//\\&/&}"
# -> Cat & Rat
```

If you want *all* `\<char>` escape sequences to be converted to literal `<char>`, use `read` (without `-r`):

```
name='Cat \&amp; Rat. C:\\temp' 
IFS= read name < <(printf %s "$name")
perl -MHTML::Entities -C -pe 'decode_entities $_' <<<"$name"
# -> Cat & Rat. C:\temp
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the GNU `recode` utility, and you only care about standalone XML entities, then you can do this:

```
name="Cat \&amp; Rat"
recode XML <<<"$name"
```

Normally, that will produce output in UTF-8. It will handle `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&quot;` and `&apos;`, as well as numeric entities (including hex).

Comment: Good to know about `recode` - if only the predefined XML entities must be recognized, this is a faster option than `perl`. On a Mac (OS X), you can install it via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) with `brew install recode`. Btw, do you know of any Linux platforms where `recode` is _preinstalled_?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you can replace SGML entity codes with the characters they represent with a simple function.  This is an incomplete proof of concept, Bash 4 only.

```
unentitize () {
    local str=$1
    local -A map=([lt]='<' [gt]='>' [quot]='"' [apos]="'")  # omit [amp]='&'
    for entity in "${!map[@]}"; do
        str=${str//&"$entity";/${map["$entity"]}}
    done
    echo "${str//&amp;/&}"
}
```

The map of entity codes is obviously incomplete.  Add the ones you need, or try to build a complete mapping programmatically from something resembling an authoritative reference.  (I just consulted http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref which is by no means authoritative.)

If you cannot use Bash 4, here is a roughly equivalent Perl script.

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { %h=(lt => "<", gt => ">", quot => q("),
    apos => qq(\x27), amp => "&");
    $re=join("|", keys %h) } s/&($re);/$h{$1}/g'
```

Comment: Treating `&amp;` as a special case doesn't make much sense here, but is crucial if you write a function to map in the other direction.

Comment: That's a handy function, nicely done. Unfortunately, due to use of associative arrays, it won't work for the OP, because OS X comes with bash _3.x_ (associative arrays require bash _4+_). You can just use `local -A map=…` (no need for separate `local` and `declare` statements).

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for your comments! Added a Perl version for Bash3.x folks.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the variable correctly

```
name='Cat & Rat'
echo "$name"
Cat & Rat
```

Comment: It's possible that `name` is being read from a file, in which case this answer may not be an option. But it does underscore the point that `bash` is not a data-processing language and is probably the wrong choice for whatever the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @chepner: Maybe your _comment_ underscores that, but the answer itself sounds more like a glib joke. The OP didn't ask for a _pure `bash`_ solution, just use in a _shell script_, where it's perfectly reasonable to call _tools_ to do this processing for you. As you stated: for all we know  - and it's not much - the fact that the sample string is stored in a _variable_ may be _incidental_.